# qgis2web not taking my rule-based styles

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

It is the first time I post here. Is qgis2web working with rule-based styling from QGIS? I've created a few rules to have a dynamic style: polygons when the scale is under 12,500 and points beyond that scale. However, when exporting it to webmap it is not taking the styles. Am I missing something out?

[image: Style in QGIS working as expected]

[image: Style in Leaflet - only polygons and it should be dynamic depending on the scale]

Please see below how I have styled it. Unfortunately, I don't think creating a point layer is going to work for this project. Just to give you some context... my polygon layer is originally stored in a Oracle database, published in Geoserver and added to QGIS as WFS. We will be updating the polygons so I don't want to be updating the points every time something changes.

[image: How I have styled the layer]

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are styling your layer with a rule-based renderer, and in each rule, checking the "Scale range" box. If so, no, I'm afraid I don't think that's supported in qgis2web. The only workaround would be to create two separate layers - one polygon, one point - with scale-dependent visibility set on the layers, not the styles.

Comment: I've updated my post adding more information.